# Using request.el to parse json to get location data from ipinfo.io

Tags: json, emacs

[Request.el](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-request) appears to be built to easily query web services that return json responses.

I would like to use it to get the city and state results that return from a query to http://ipinfo.io

If, from the command-line, I issue the following:

```
curl https://ipinfo.io
```

I get back the following:

```
{
  "ip": "24.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "hostname": "cpe-xx-xxx-xxx-x.xxx.xxx.xx.com",
  "city": "Brooklyn",
  "region": "New York",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "40.6406,-74.0169",
  "org": "AS12271 Time Warner Cable Internet LLC",
  "postal": "11220"
}%
```

I would like to pull out the "city" and "state" values and put them into a single variable as a string such as:

```
(setq my-location "Brooklyn, NY")
```

While the resolve.el page has a great deal of documentation, I'm not a programmer and I simply don't understand how to get the information I need. I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track, but I just lack the knowlege of how to get where I want to go.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
    (require 'request)
    (request "https://ipinfo.io"
             :parser 'json-read
             :success (cl-function
                       (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
                         (message "I sent: %S" (assoc-default 'args data))
                         (message "Data is %s" data )
                         (message "Result is %s, %s" (assoc-default 'city data) (assoc-default 'region data)))))
```

(Not tested because I have an internal IP address and therefore don't have access to city/region data.)

Comment: `ipinfo.io` is going to see your external ip, you can test it.

Comment: I don't have city or region in my response, so I don't know that my solution actually answers OP's question:

<pre>
$ curl   https://ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "100.106.148.21",
  "bogon": true
}
</pre>

Comment: huh... not really related to the question but I don't understand how this is possible. what happens when you just go to the website? does it show your external ip and country?

Comment: The site classifies my ip address as "carrier grade NAT" and therefore "bogon".